# Truncated incorrect integer value MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, truncated

I have a table `ABC` that has many columns, two of which are: 
`ID - VARCHAR(10)` and  `ROLE VARCHAR(10)`.
Now I have been trying to update the column `ROLE` using the `ID` and this is the query:

```
UPDATE TABLE ABC
SET    ROLE='READ_ONLY'
WHERE  ID='AB234PQR'
```

Now for some unknown reason, i have been getting the error - `truncated incorrect integer value`. I have no idea where I am going wrong.I have been banging my head over this for a while now.

I have visited other questions with the similar title.All use `convert` or some other function in `where` clause, But I have not used any such thing, still it gives me the same error.

I checked the table description and it seems fine. Where can I be going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are there any triggers on this table?

Comment: @P.Salmon I think that could be the issue. I did create some triggers recently.I will have a look at them and get back to you. Thanks, mate.

Comment: @P.Salmon You were right!! There were triggers on that table creating the issue!! Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
UPDATE ABC
SET    ROLE='READ_ONLY'
WHERE  ID='AB234PQR'
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to update table entries is:

```
UPDATE `table_name` 
SET `column_name` = 'value'
WHERE `column_name2` = 'value2';
```

It is as well recommended to use backticks around table names and column names, just like the way you can see in my snippet above.

Therefore using

```
UPDATE `ABC`
SET    `ROLE` = 'READ_ONLY'
WHERE  `ID` = 'AB234PQR'
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I will give this a try. Thanks.